# ecplipse not giving suggestions

Tags: eclipse, api

My eclipse has always worked perfectly, but recently it just stopped giving suggestions when I write for example `canvas.`, or `Math.`, nothing comes up. Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? it is really annoying and makes everything I do take atleast twice the time.

Answer (score 0):

window -> preferences -> editor -> content assist

Comment: dosnt exist I'm afraid, I use Eclipse Juno, Ive looked in general editor and android editor, but no checkbox for "Content assist"